# Code not iterating over whole dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

so I have the following function:

```
def check(g,s):
    for keys, value in g.items():
        for w, val in enumerate(g[keys]):
            print(s, g[keys][w], w)
            if(s==g[keys][w]):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
```

- `g` is a dictionary with an integer as a key and a list as a value
- `s` is an integer I am looking for in the value lists

And I have the following data (a dictionary with an integer as the key and a list as a value):

```
d={1.4953487812212205: [1, 1.2228445449938519], 2.23606797749979: [2, 1.4953487812212205], 3.309750919646873: [3, 1.8192720851062585]}
```

The data is actually much longer but I reduced it for our simplicity.

That `check` function is looking for a specific value in the list of every key in the dictionary and return a 1 or 0.  Now the problem is if I take the code and run it as a standalone (fixed dictionary and just run the check function), the code works fine (if I search `3`, it will return a `1`).

But if I integrate it to my larger code, the `w` variable never increments and it also only checks the first dictionary entry (only 1 key) instead of all of them and it never finds `3` (since it never gets there).

What can the problem be?  I can't seem to put a finger on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't return 0 until you have checked all the values:

```
def check(g,s):
    for keys, value in g.items():
        for w, val in enumerate(g[keys]):
            print(s, g[keys][w], w)
            if(s==g[keys][w]):
                return 1
    return 0
```

Since you are iterating over items(), you don't have to re-lookup the values using the keys:

```
def check(g,s):
    for keys, value in g.items():
        for w, val in enumerate(value):
            print(s, val, w)
            if(s==val):
                return 1
    return 0
```

If you use any with a nested generator, you can accomplish the same thing (just look at the dict's values() collection, since you don't seem to care what the key is):

```
def check(g,s):
    if any(s in vlist for vlist in g.values()):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

And since True = 1 and False = 0, this further reduces to:

```
def check(g,s):
    return any(s in vlist for vlist in g.values())
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer!  Thank you.